# apache mod rewrite rule working but needs modified

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am building a classified ads website and I want to rewrite the following url
www.domain.co.uk/car/bmw/bmw-316-mot-1-owner/123

to 
www.doamin.co.uk/view-ad/ad=123

I have the following lines in my .htaccess file:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^cars/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ view-ad/?ad=$1 [NC,L]

how can i replace cars with anything (such as a category name)/sub category name/ad title/ad id

ad title could look something like "bmw-316-for-sale-£1995-ono" so could include symbols and special characters

The above works if I enter domain.co.uk/car/123 but if I try to replace cars with [A-Za-z0-9] it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your urls always end with `/the_id`, you can match *everything*:

```
RewriteRule ^car/(.*/)?([0-9]+)$ view-ad/?ad=$2 [NC,L]
```

The `(.*/)?` fragment lets us matching anything (including nothing if we are on /car/123).

Don't forget to enable and check the debug logs for the rewrite module ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2,
[LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) if you have troubles with rules that don't apply.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).